# Parse to Heroku migration: Parse-server cloud code doesn't work

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I succeeded to migrate my app from Parse to Heroku, now my AppDelegate use this code:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"xxxxxxxx";
    configuration.clientKey = @"xxxxxxxx";
    configuration.server = @"http://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse";
}]];
```

and not

```
//    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxxxxxx"
//                      clientKey:@"xxxxxxxx"];
//    [PFUser enableRevocableSessionInBackground];
```

Everything works except the cloud code, when I run a cloud code, this is the error from Simulator: `[Error]: Invalid function. (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)`

Here is my cloud file path: `/Users/Viny/heroku/parse-server-example/cloud/main.js`

I updated and push it with the same main.js from Parse.

Here is my index.js:

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({  
    databaseURI: process.env.DATABASE_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',  
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: 'xxxxxxx',  
    masterKey: 'xxxxxxx',
    fileKey: 'xxxxxxx',  
    clientKey: 'xxxxxxx',
    serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' 
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a web site.');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Cloud code works as expected with Parse, but doesn't work with Heroku...

Comment: Can you share your cloud clode, also show me how r u calling it

Comment: @KnightCoder Thank you so much KnightCoder to help me! I made another reply on this post, please let me know how to achieve this. :)

Comment: @KnightCoder Hi KnightCoder, I have one last problem with migration: <Relation> in parse doesn't work in MongoLab, please have a look on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689128/parse-to-heroku-migration-mongolab-pfrelation-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this 
configuration.server = @"http://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse";
Do this
configuration.server = @"http://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/";

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've found the problem, I've two "personal apps" on Heroku for my iOS app: "chilln" (my iOS app name) and "rocky-reef-28464" (automatically created by following this tuto: https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/)

I changed my configuration.server to : http://rocky-reef-28464.herokuapp.com/parse/

and now it seems to recognize the cloud code, just this error on simulator: `[Error]: <null> (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)`

Here is a screen of my personal apps on Heroku: [image]

Should I have only one personal apps ?

chilln has the add-ons MongoLab and cfg var: "app_id", "master_key", "mongolab_url", "parse_mount". rocky-reef-28464 hasn't add-ons MongoLab but has only one cfg var: "DATABASE_URI", and has the git heroku repo (I think)

What I've to do ? Merge the two app to one ?

Comment: Works as expected after merging two apps